# Mongoose nested group by with sorting on nested field

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have data in my collection like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b29fc8a0d206c33115cdf87"),
    "Cost" : 20,
    "Desc" : "Cost of purchase",
    "Category" : "C1",
    "Vendor" : "Vendor 2"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b29fc8a0d206c33115cdf88"),
    "Cost" : 40,
    "Desc" : "Cost of repairs",
    "Category" : "C1",
    "Vendor" : "Vendor 1",
}........ so on
```

I want to do nested aggregation on this to get data with sorting on Vendor like this:

```
[
    {
        "_id": "Cost of purchase",
        "Value": [
            {
                "Vendor": "Vendor 1",
                "Sum_Cost": 40
            },
            {
                "Vendor": "Vendor 2",
                "Sum_Cost": 20
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

But I'm not getting the data sorted on Vendors. I'm getting the data like:

```
[
    {
        "_id": "Cost of purchase",
        "Value": [
            {
                "Vendor": "Vendor 2",
                "Sum_Cost": 20
            },
            {
                "Vendor": "Vendor 1",
                "Sum_Cost": 40
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

This is the code i have done so far with nested grouping on Desc and Vendor to get sum of cost. But my sorting isn't working as it suppose to sort the data inside array of object with Vendor:

```
let aggreArray = [{
  $group: {
      _id: {
          Desc: "$Desc",
          Vendor: "$Vendor"
      },
      sum: {
          "$sum": "$Cost"
      }
  }
}, {
  $group: {
      _id: "$_id.Desc",
      Value: {
          $push: {
              Vendor: "$_id.Vendor",
              value: "$sum"
          }
      }
  }
},{
  $sort: { "Value.Vendor": 1}
}];
db.collection.aggregate(aggreArray).toArray(function (err, docs) {
    console.log(docs);  
});
```

Comment: Use `$sort` in second stage before pushing into the array with `sum` ... You are using in third stage

Comment: Thank you @AnthonyWinzlet. This worked.

Comment: BTW, Your code is working as well... check it here https://mongoplayground.net/p/V-Ms6MKnNqz

Comment: No it wasn't. I shared only few data not the whole data. Check it here https://mongoplayground.net/p/XY533yvPa-t

Answer (score 0):

I found @Ashh's solution works, but just to make it clear so we know this question already has solution instead of reading from comment, I add this answer.

```
let aggreArray = [{
  $group: {
      _id: {
          Desc: "$Desc",
          Vendor: "$Vendor"
      },
      sum: {
          "$sum": "$Cost"
      }
  }
},
{ $sort: { "Value.Vendor": 1} },
{
  $group: {
      _id: "$_id.Desc",
      Value: {
          $push: {
              Vendor: "$_id.Vendor",
              value: "$sum"
          }
      }
  }
}];
db.collection.aggregate(aggreArray).toArray(function (err, docs) {
    console.log(docs);  
});
```

Based on @Ashh's answer on the comment section.